# Nested if statement in C

Tags: c, if-statement

My code need to execute only one case path from 3x2 table which is; for Male 140 to 160 cm: short, 161 to 180 cm: medium; 181 to 199 cm: tall and for Female 120 to 140 cm: short, 141 to 165 cm: medium and 166 to 180 cm: tall.

For example, if i enter 153 cm woman, output is need to be only medium. But now my code gives output if i enter 153 cm woman, medium & tall together at the end.

How can i edit this code so far to execute for only one case for two combinations, age and length, and one of the three option for length; for example if i enter 153 cm woman, it will need say only medium.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int length;
    char gender;

    printf("enter gender: ");
    scanf("%c", &gender);

    printf("enter length: ");
    scanf("%d", &length);

    if (gender == 'M' || 'm') {

        if (length <= 140 && length <= 160 ) {

            printf ("short");
        }

        if (length <= 161 && length <= 180 ) {

            printf ("medium");

        }

        if (length <= 181 && length <= 199 ) {

            printf ("tall");
        }

        if (gender == 'W' || gender == 'w') {

            if (length <= 120 || length <=140) {

                printf("short");

                if (length <=141 || length <=165) {

                    printf ("medium");

                    if (length <=166 || length <=180) {

                        printf ("tall");}

                        else {

                            printf("error");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (gender == 'M' || 'm')` is always true. Did you mean `if (gender == 'M' || gender == 'm')`? And `if (gender == 'W' || gender == 'w')` will never be true as it is _inside_ the `if` that checks if the gender is Male. Also, all your `length` conditions are wrong. `length <= 140 && length <= 160` -> `length >= 140 && length <= 160` etc

Comment: ah yes, typo error in that line, this should be (gender == 'M' || gender ==  'm') for capital/lower case. thanks. trying this way now.

Comment: still doesnt work, how should i seperate man and woman blocks, i am confusing  curly bracket using. (even inside of blocks)

Comment: `if(gender == 'M' || gender == 'm') { /* length checks */ } else if(gender == 'W' || gender == 'w') { /* length checks */ }`

Comment: man block ok but woman block has still problem 

output is: 

enter gender: w                                                                                                                                              
enter length: 142                                                                                                                                            
shortmediumtall

Comment: Your `length` conditions for the woman blocks are incorrect. Compare it with the man blocks and you'll see it

Comment: thanks cool guy, it works perfectly now. and i want a add error for char entry except w/W and m/M. where and how should i put this else or else if in my blocks?

Comment: `if (gender == 'M' || gender == 'm') { /* length checks */ } else if (gender == 'W' || gender == 'w') { /* length checks */ } else { /* Error */ }`. You should read up on a good C tutorial so that you can grasp the basics of C

Comment: thx again. and any suggestion for good tutorials? i cant find any good tut for nested if/else statements.

Comment: @kadir *any suggestion for good tutorials?* The best tutorial is to just keep coding and solving problems. You'll learn along the way.  For instance:  instead of `if (gender == 'W' || gender == 'w')`, you can use `if ( toupper( gender ) == 'W' )`, or even better you can validate the `gender` input immediately when the user enters it and convert it to a consistent case right then.

Comment: What should happen if the height for a male is shorter than 140 cm or taller than 199 cm — or for a female if the height is shorter than 120 cm or taller than 180 cm?  Must you use nested if statements or would a solution that's table driven be acceptable?  These are design issues.  Your outputs do not end with a newline; that isn't entirely satisfactory — at least, it wouldn't be OK to me.

Answer (score 1):

For below lines, it has to be length >= 161.
Pls check similar lines for this.

```
   if (length <= 161 && length <= 180 ) {

        printf ("medium");

    }
```

Comment: thanx ill check.

Answer (score 1):

kadir you have done a number of mistakes , no problem . Practice makes a man perfect ...!
Compare your code and your code that i changed .. and realize the mistakes . Explanation is given as comments in code .

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

int length;
char gender;

printf("enter gender: ");
scanf("%c", &gender);

printf("enter length: ");
scanf("%d", &length);

if (gender == 'M' ||gender == 'm') { //comparison should be done in both sides of or

    if (length >= 140 && length <= 160 ) {

        printf ("short");
    }

    else if (length >= 161 && length <= 180 ) {

        printf ("medium");

    }

   else if (length >= 181 && length <= 199 ) {

        printf ("tall");
    }
}
 else if (gender == 'W' || gender == 'w') {
        if (length >= 120 && length <=140) {

            printf("short");
        }
          else  if (length >=141 && length <=165) { // & should be used.

                printf ("medium");
            }
              else  if (length >=166 && length <=180) {

                    printf ("tall");}

                    else {   /* if you are using else simply , it corresponds to the last if not all the if's in front so try using if else .*/

                        printf("error");
                    }
                }



return 0;
 }
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare length in an exclusive range. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int length;
char gender;

printf("enter gender: ");
scanf("%c", &gender);

printf("enter length: ");
scanf("%d", &length);

if (gender == 'M' || gender == 'm'){
    if (length <= 160 )
        printf ("short\n");
    if (161 <= length && length <= 180)
        printf ("medium\n");
    if (181 <= length && length <= 199)
        printf ("tall\n");

}

if (gender == 'W' || gender == 'w'){
    if (length <= 140) 
        printf ("short\n");
    if (141 <= length && length <= 165)
        printf ("medium\n");
    if (166 <= length && length <= 180)
        printf ("tall\n");
        if(length>=180)
        printf("error \n");
 }
 else if(gender != 'm'|| gender!='M'|| gender!='w'||gender!='W')
 printf("error");
 return 0;

}
```

Comment: Also consider trying out either topper(gender) or tolower(gender) functions from the ctype library :)

Comment: thanks, how can i add an error message for wrong char entry, which is not m/M or w/W? i mean user can only enter m/M or w/W. otherwise program will say error.

Comment: Consider using `else if`s @reedx8

Comment: @kadir add an else condition with the error message you would like. Perhaps have user repeat using a do-while loop as well around all of the conditions until user enters a w or m. So, else{printf(“error message here”)}